# Passing QMouseEvent in a signal-slot

Tags: qt

I am trying to send a QMouseEvent through a signal, when I am executing this

```
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    emit mouseEvent(event);
}
```

on debugging I found that the event is right.
But on receiving it in a slot, some value in event are wrong. Like event->button() is wrong and event->globalX() is right, but event->x() is wrong.
I don't understand why the event is getting changed when passing through slot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do that in the mentioned way. As you probably noticed, the `QMouseEvent` pointer points to non constant object, so that nothing guaranties that it will not change. Most possibly the `event` object got modified during its propagation to the parent objects, so you should not rely on it. Instead use `QMouseEvent` properties to pass through, such as position, etc.:

```
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    emit mouseEventCaught(event->pos());
}
```

Comment: yeah, but i need to pass enums- QEvent::Type, and Qt::MouseButton, they are not registered as QMetaType, and QMouseEvent also cannot be passed in signal and slots. And one thing noticeable is that it always conveys right coordinates in globalPos but it has always (-1,-2) in pos and some random value in button. It is consistent.

Comment: Why don't pass enums as integers? Declare signal as `mouseEventCaught(int, int)` and emit it as `mouseEventCaught(event->type(), event->button())`.